# Suppose $R$ is an integral domain, $a, b\in R$ are nonzero. Suppose $x$ is nonzero, then $x\in(a, b)$ IFF $x=sa-tb$ for some $s, t\in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

**The Problem**: Suppose $R$ is an integral domain, $a, b\in R$ are nonzero. Suppose $x$ is nonzero, then $x\in(a, b)$ IFF $x=sa-tb$ for some $s, t\in R$.

**My Attempt**: Certainly this is true if $R$ is an Euclidean domain: if $x\in(a, b)$, then $x\in(d)$ where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Note that $d$ can be written as a $R$-linear combination $d=ax+by$, hence $x=z(ax+by)$ for some $z$ thus $x=zxa+zyb=sa-tb$, where $s=zx$ and $t=-zy$; conversely, if $x=sa-tb$ then clearly $x\in(a, b)$. But what if $R$ is an integral domain that is **NOT** an Euclidean domain? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition of $(a,b)$?

Comment: That follows immediately from definition of $\,(a,b)R = aR + bR$ as an ideal sum

Comment: I rrecommend that that you review the basic of ideals, since you need to master that before you attack deeper matters (such as Dedekind Hasse norms in your prior question). It appears you may be trying to run before you've learned to walk.

Comment: @BillDubuque I completely agree-I believed that this is probably trivial from the very beginning and I somehow struggle to see it-even after the link and the explanation you provided here.

Comment: How does you book define the ideal $(a,b)?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque $(a, b)$ is the smallest ideal containing $\{a, b\}$, which was shown to be $\underset{I \text{an ideal}, \\A\subset I}{\cap} I$.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you for all the help Bill-I finally cracked it.